# Flutter need help in parsing data in ListView

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I want to know how can I convert this(for reference have a look at the screenshot attached below) JSON data into a list format in listView.builder.
Want to show latitude and longitude in the list

[image]

```
    {
    "Hyderabad" : [
        {
            "id": "chargeId",
            "latitude" : 17.365420555196007,
            "longitude" : 78.54119183209222,
            "name" : "Charge And Drive Charging Station"
        },
        {
            "id": "chargeId1",
            "latitude" : 17.387480524361507,
            "longitude" : 78.51581096594167,
            "name" : "Electric Vehicle Charging Station"
        }
    ],

    "Banglore" : [
        {
            "id": "chargeId",
            "latitude" : 12.978549585750843,
            "longitude" : 77.59097742148764,
            "name" : "Electric Vehicle Charging Station"
        },
        {
            "id": "chargeId1",
            "latitude" : 12.972527571466378,
            "longitude" : 77.54737543231649,
            "name" : "Charzer Charging Station Bangluru"

        }
    ],
    "Delhi" : [
        {
            "id": "chargeId",
            "latitude" : 28.638023239349177,
            "longitude" : 77.2193154296281,
            "name" : "Electric Vehicle Charging Station New Delhi"
        },
        {
            "id": "chargeId1",
            "latitude" : 28.664376657655705,
            "longitude" : 77.08421387364653,
            "name" : "Electric Vehicle Charging Station Paschim Vihar new delhi"
        }
    ],
    "Haryana" : [
        {
            "id": "chargeId",
            "latitude": 28.419348425880248,
            "longitude": 77.31062471844143,
            "name": "Tata Charging Station"
        },
        {
            "id": "chargeId1",
            "latitude": 28.396055078900797,
            "longitude": 77.32257812582378,
            "name": "98WF+53V, Sector 36, Sector 15, Faridabad, Haryana 121007"
        }
    ],
    "UttarPradesh" : [
        {
            "id": "chargeId",
            "latitude" : 28.574105613931682,
            "longitude" : 77.3332671026249,
            "name" : "EESL Charging Station Noida"
        },
        {
            "id":"chargeId1",
            "latitude" : 28.623488529263664,
            "longitude" : 77.35702730533745,
            "name" : "A1 MOTORS"
        }
    ],

    "Chandigarh" : [
        {
            "id": "chargeId",
            "latitude": 30.71576216371489,
            "longitude": 76.83314092409462,
            "name": "Pradeep Traders"
        },
        {
            "id": "chargeId1",
            "latitude": 30.698346233404187,
            "longitude": 76.79571874441227,
            "name": "Tata Power Charging Station"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also here's my model class

```
    class CoordChandigarh {
/*
{
  "id": "chargeId",
  "latitude": 30.71576216371489,
  "longitude": 76.83314092409462,
  "name": "Pradeep Traders"
} 
*/

  String? id;
  double? latitude;
  double? longitude;
  String? name;

  CoordChandigarh({
    this.id,
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
    this.name,
  });
  CoordChandigarh.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"]?.toString();
    latitude = json["latitude"]?.toDouble();
    longitude = json["longitude"]?.toDouble();
    name = json["name"]?.toString();
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = id;
    data["latitude"] = latitude;
    data["longitude"] = longitude;
    data["name"] = name;
    return data;
  }
}

class CoordUttarPradesh {
/*
{
  "id": "chargeId",
  "latitude": 28.574105613931682,
  "longitude": 77.3332671026249,
  "name": "EESL Charging Station Noida"
} 
*/

  String? id;
  double? latitude;
  double? longitude;
  String? name;

  CoordUttarPradesh({
    this.id,
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
    this.name,
  });
  CoordUttarPradesh.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"]?.toString();
    latitude = json["latitude"]?.toDouble();
    longitude = json["longitude"]?.toDouble();
    name = json["name"]?.toString();
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = id;
    data["latitude"] = latitude;
    data["longitude"] = longitude;
    data["name"] = name;
    return data;
  }
}

class CoordHaryana {
/*
{
  "id": "chargeId",
  "latitude": 28.419348425880248,
  "longitude": 77.31062471844143,
  "name": "Tata Charging Station"
} 
*/

  String? id;
  double? latitude;
  double? longitude;
  String? name;

  CoordHaryana({
    this.id,
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
    this.name,
  });
  CoordHaryana.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"]?.toString();
    latitude = json["latitude"]?.toDouble();
    longitude = json["longitude"]?.toDouble();
    name = json["name"]?.toString();
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = id;
    data["latitude"] = latitude;
    data["longitude"] = longitude;
    data["name"] = name;
    return data;
  }
}

class CoordDelhi {
/*
{
  "id": "chargeId",
  "latitude": 28.638023239349177,
  "longitude": 77.2193154296281,
  "name": "Electric Vehicle Charging Station New Delhi"
} 
*/

  String? id;
  double? latitude;
  double? longitude;
  String? name;

  CoordDelhi({
    this.id,
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
    this.name,
  });
  CoordDelhi.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"]?.toString();
    latitude = json["latitude"]?.toDouble();
    longitude = json["longitude"]?.toDouble();
    name = json["name"]?.toString();
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = id;
    data["latitude"] = latitude;
    data["longitude"] = longitude;
    data["name"] = name;
    return data;
  }
}

class CoordBanglore {
/*
{
  "id": "chargeId",
  "latitude": 12.978549585750843,
  "longitude": 77.59097742148764,
  "name": "Electric Vehicle Charging Station"
} 
*/

  String? id;
  double? latitude;
  double? longitude;
  String? name;

  CoordBanglore({
    this.id,
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
    this.name,
  });
  CoordBanglore.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"]?.toString();
    latitude = json["latitude"]?.toDouble();
    longitude = json["longitude"]?.toDouble();
    name = json["name"]?.toString();
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = id;
    data["latitude"] = latitude;
    data["longitude"] = longitude;
    data["name"] = name;
    return data;
  }
}

class CoordHyderabad {
/*
{
  "id": "chargeId",
  "latitude": 17.365420555196007,
  "longitude": 78.54119183209222,
  "name": "Charge And Drive Charging Station"
} 
*/

  String? id;
  double? latitude;
  double? longitude;
  String? name;

  CoordHyderabad({
    this.id,
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
    this.name,
  });
  CoordHyderabad.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"]?.toString();
    latitude = json["latitude"]?.toDouble();
    longitude = json["longitude"]?.toDouble();
    name = json["name"]?.toString();
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = id;
    data["latitude"] = latitude;
    data["longitude"] = longitude;
    data["name"] = name;
    return data;
  }
}

class Coord {
/*
{
  "Hyderabad": [
    {
      "id": "chargeId",
      "latitude": 17.365420555196007,
      "longitude": 78.54119183209222,
      "name": "Charge And Drive Charging Station"
    }
  ],
  "Banglore": [
    {
      "id": "chargeId",
      "latitude": 12.978549585750843,
      "longitude": 77.59097742148764,
      "name": "Electric Vehicle Charging Station"
    }
  ],
  "Delhi": [
    {
      "id": "chargeId",
      "latitude": 28.638023239349177,
      "longitude": 77.2193154296281,
      "name": "Electric Vehicle Charging Station New Delhi"
    }
  ],
  "Haryana": [
    {
      "id": "chargeId",
      "latitude": 28.419348425880248,
      "longitude": 77.31062471844143,
      "name": "Tata Charging Station"
    }
  ],
  "UttarPradesh": [
    {
      "id": "chargeId",
      "latitude": 28.574105613931682,
      "longitude": 77.3332671026249,
      "name": "EESL Charging Station Noida"
    }
  ],
  "Chandigarh": [
    {
      "id": "chargeId",
      "latitude": 30.71576216371489,
      "longitude": 76.83314092409462,
      "name": "Pradeep Traders"
    }
  ]
} 
*/

  List<CoordHyderabad?>? hyderabad;
  List<CoordBanglore?>? banglore;
  List<CoordDelhi?>? delhi;
  List<CoordHaryana?>? haryana;
  List<CoordUttarPradesh?>? uttarPradesh;
  List<CoordChandigarh?>? chandigarh;

  Coord({
    this.hyderabad,
    this.banglore,
    this.delhi,
    this.haryana,
    this.uttarPradesh,
    this.chandigarh,
  });
  Coord.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  if (json["Hyderabad"] != null) {
  final v = json["Hyderabad"];
  final arr0 = <CoordHyderabad>[];
  v.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(CoordHyderabad.fromJson(v));
  });
    hyderabad = arr0;
    }
  if (json["Banglore"] != null) {
  final v = json["Banglore"];
  final arr0 = <CoordBanglore>[];
  v.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(CoordBanglore.fromJson(v));
  });
    banglore = arr0;
    }
  if (json["Delhi"] != null) {
  final v = json["Delhi"];
  final arr0 = <CoordDelhi>[];
  v.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(CoordDelhi.fromJson(v));
  });
    delhi = arr0;
    }
  if (json["Haryana"] != null) {
  final v = json["Haryana"];
  final arr0 = <CoordHaryana>[];
  v.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(CoordHaryana.fromJson(v));
  });
    haryana = arr0;
    }
  if (json["UttarPradesh"] != null) {
  final v = json["UttarPradesh"];
  final arr0 = <CoordUttarPradesh>[];
  v.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(CoordUttarPradesh.fromJson(v));
  });
    uttarPradesh = arr0;
    }
  if (json["Chandigarh"] != null) {
  final v = json["Chandigarh"];
  final arr0 = <CoordChandigarh>[];
  v.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(CoordChandigarh.fromJson(v));
  });
    chandigarh = arr0;
    }
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (hyderabad != null) {
      final v = hyderabad;
      final arr0 = [];
  v!.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(v!.toJson());
  });
      data["Hyderabad"] = arr0;
    }
    if (banglore != null) {
      final v = banglore;
      final arr0 = [];
  v!.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(v!.toJson());
  });
      data["Banglore"] = arr0;
    }
    if (delhi != null) {
      final v = delhi;
      final arr0 = [];
  v!.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(v!.toJson());
  });
      data["Delhi"] = arr0;
    }
    if (haryana != null) {
      final v = haryana;
      final arr0 = [];
  v!.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(v!.toJson());
  });
      data["Haryana"] = arr0;
    }
    if (uttarPradesh != null) {
      final v = uttarPradesh;
      final arr0 = [];
  v!.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(v!.toJson());
  });
      data["UttarPradesh"] = arr0;
    }
    if (chandigarh != null) {
      final v = chandigarh;
      final arr0 = [];
  v!.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(v!.toJson());
  });
      data["Chandigarh"] = arr0;
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

Using Future builder to get the data but I may not know how to get a List of data from JSON file here's my Listview Data along with parsing JSON method

```
FutureBuilder(
                    future: _custJson(),
                    builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
                      // var data = coordList;
                      var newData = snapshot.data.toString();
                      print("this is delhi data ");
                      return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: newData.length,
                          itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ListTile(
                                title: Text(newData),
                              ));
                    }),


    Future<void> _custJson() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/test.json');
    final data = await jsonDecode(response);
    final coord = Coord.fromJson(data);
    return data;
    print(coord);
    // final coord = Coord.fromJson(data) ;
    // Map<String, dynamic> userMap = jsonDecode(response);
    // var user = Coord.fromJson(userMap);
    // String json = jsonEncode({user});
    // print(json);
  }
```

Help me please I am badly stuck on this issue.
Appreciate your time and efforts

Comment: By the way, getting the success response from the JSON file using _custJson() method

Comment: Are you getting errors from fetching data or parsing data from json ?

Comment: No error no help.

Comment: want to get the data in the list I don't understand how can I do that, though I tried different different ways to do that but unable to

Comment: return the data from your custJson function.

Comment: data variable? @stacktrace2234

Comment: Yeah, `future: _custJson(),` this expect a future. If you don't return anything, it won't work.

Comment: I did it. it worked as well @stacktrace2234 but now it's giving me the data in JSON format on the listview! how do I convert the data in list format?

Comment: You have to start giving us more informations. Edit the question and give us the error, what you want, what you have now.

Comment: @stacktrace2234 updated the question, also added a screenshot for reference please have a look at it! appreciate your time thank you.